# K-means в dash plotly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

Как отобразить нижепредставленный код для px.scatter?

```
X = df[['x','y']].to_numpy()
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2).fit(X)
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1], c=kmeans.labels_, cmap='rainbow')
```

Если пишу,

```
px.scatter(X, color=kmeans.labels_)
```

то выводиться непрерывная расцветка. А мне нужно ее в дискертный вид привести.
[image: continous]

Comment: А что не так, что не получается? Добавьте больше подробностей в вопрос.

Comment: Вот здесь ответы почитайте, например: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60962274/plotly-how-to-change-the-colorscheme-of-a-plotly-express-scatterplot

Comment: Попробуйте начать с варианта `px.scatter(x=X[:,0],y=X[:,1], color=kmeans.labels_)`, а дальше насчёт цвета и цветовых схем читайте ссылку, которую я привёл.

Comment: @CrazyElf пока дополняла вопрос, вы уже ответили также )

Comment: @CrazyElf таким образом он мне рисует непрерывную раскраску, а мне надо дискретную. Также не могу найти аналога ```cmap``` для ```px.scatter```. Может вы знаете ?

Comment: Попробуйте всё-таки почитать ссылку, которую я выше дал. Там несколько вариантов работы с цветами и цветовыми схемами приведено. И я не уверен, что у вас правильная отрисовка точек судя по оси `x` под названием `index`, попробуйте всё-таки вариант `x=X[:,0],y=X[:,1]` тоже посмотреть.